# What node I can I optimise by tree reduction in bison?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

If I make a compiler where the output of bison is a tree.  I want to optimise that tree by reducing the tree for constant expressions. For example,
if I have an `(if_else_node)` I can reduce this node by checking `(expression_if == true)` then I don't need to visit the `(else_node)`.

Another example of reduction:

If I have an `(add_node)` and I have the expression  `(7+9+2+6)` I can reduce this to `(add_node) (18 + 6)`.

My question is what another nodes can I reduce in the bison tree?

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes an incorrect assumption that the output of bison is a parse tree. The bison parser generator tool only builds a parser. It does not implicitly perform any default actions on a successful parse, such as building a parse tree, although there are other parser generators or compiler-compiler toolsets that do.

To have a bison parser build a parse tree as the result of the parse you would have to specifically provide your own code to do that.

However, if you had provided such a parse tree builder, you could get the tree nodes that you describe, and you could do the constant folding you describe.

Your question is not really about bison, but about how to perform intermediate code optimisations in a parse tree. There are ample descriptions of these phase of a compiler in compiler writing text books. However I can help you with identifying some further ones.

It is also not clear if you are asking about *constant folding* optimisations specifically, or the whole spectrum of intermediate code optimisations.

You have mentioned two, the optimisation of boolean expressions which can result in *dead code removal* from a conditional. These conditionals can also occur in loops, which can result in loop removal also:

- `(expression_while == false)` can cause the whole loop to be removed.

You have mentioned (add_node), but of course all integer arithmetic operators could be evaluated at compiler-time.

Another useful form of optimisation that can be performed are various forms of arithmetic constant manipulation. Some simple examples:

- `(add_node)(x+0)`  => `(x)`
- `(multiply_node)(x*1)`  => `(x)`
- `(multiply_node)(x*0)` => `(0)`

Hopefully that is what you seek?